# Android load html data into chrome custom tabs

Tags: android, html, webview, google-chrome-devtools

I want to use chrome custom tabs in my app. I found how to load data from url into tabs, but i didnt find, how to load data from string value with html-tags. How to make analogous functional from webview-example:

```
webViewContent.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlText, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

in chrome custom tabs?

Comment: Chrome custom tabs can't do that

Answer (score 0):

Its not directly possible to load a HTML string or local HTML file  having file:// url to chrome custom tabs.

But you can implement Local Server to render offline html content in Custom chrome tabs. refer following URL.

https://bitbucket.org/snippets/pkumarad/qAk6x